# Using a variable to define my method

Tags: php, api, function, constants

I have a function which is a wrapper for a Post Affiliate Pro API call. I'm trying to pass an optional argument to my function to set the data range. The API uses the following method in one of its own arguments:

```
Gpf_Data_Filter::RANGE_LAST_7_DAYS
```

Here it is in the context of my own function. I want to pass the $range option. The way I'm doing it obviously gives an undefined constant warning and then causes a fatal error.

```
function getSales($session, $userID, $campaignID, $range = RANGE_LAST_7_DAYS ){
    $request = new Pap_Api_TransactionsGrid($session);
    $request->addFilter('dateinserted', Gpf_Data_Filter::DATERANGE_IS, Gpf_Data_Filter::$range);
    // ...rest of function
```

What would I need to pass as a third argument to replicate this? :

```
Gpf_Data_Filter::RANGE_LAST_7_DAYS
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your question correctly, why can't you just use `$range = Gpf_Data_Filter::RANGE_LAST_7_DAYS` as the default fourth argument in your function?

Comment: Yes thats it. Well done for understanding my poorly explained question. Definitely one of those kick myself moments.

Comment: Can you post this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP allows you to use constants from another class as default arguments for a function or a class method, so this should be perfectly fine:

```
function getSales($session, $userID, $campaignID, $range = Gpf_Data_Filter::RANGE_LAST_7_DAYS)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work...

```
function getSales($session, $userID, $campaignID, $range = null){
    $range = $range ?: Gpf_Data_filter::RANGE_LAST_7_DAYS;
    $request = new Pap_Api_TransactionsGrid($session);
    $request->addFilter('dateinserted', Gpf_Data_Filter::DATERANGE_IS, $range);
    // ...rest of function
```

Answer (score 1):

You have basically three options:

1. Pass the actual constant:

   ```
   function getSales(..., $range = Gpf_Data_Filter::RANGE_LAST_7_DAYS)
   ```
2. Define your own values or constants and map them to the official constants:

   ```
   function getSales(..., $range = 'seven') {
       static $ranges = [
           'one'   => Gpf_Data_Filter::RANGE_LAST_1_DAY,
           ...
           'seven' => Gpf_Data_Filter::RANGE_LAST_7_DAYS,
       ];
       $range = $ranges[$range];
   ```
3. Accept a number and construct the constant name from it:

   ```
   function getSales(..., $range = 7) {
       $range = constant("Gpf_Data_Filter::RANGE_LAST_$range_DAYS");
   ```

Which one works best depends on how varied those constants are and whether you want to expose the original constants to the user of your class or not.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to silkfire:

```
function getSales($session, $userID, $campaignID, $range = Gpf_Data_Filter::RANGE_LAST_7_DAYS ){
    $request = new Pap_Api_TransactionsGrid($session);
    $request->addFilter('dateinserted', Gpf_Data_Filter::DATERANGE_IS, $range);
```

I have now set a 2 cups of coffee threshold before posting on here in future.